# Node-Red Send Binary

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, node-red

I was just introduced to `Node-Red` after asking around for some suggestions on an `IoT` setup. I have a piece of javascript code that is sending data to a web socket. The code that it is sending is in a `HEX` format and is sent to the web socket.

I am trying to replicate this using `node-red` and I am having some trouble figuring out which node to use for sending the data.

Vanilla Javascript:

```
function connectToSocket() {

    // Try to connect to the socket
    try {

        // Create our socket connection
        connection = new WebSocket('ws://' + gatewayIP + ':8000');
        connection.binaryType = "arraybuffer";

        // Failed to  create the socket connection  
    } catch (e) {

        // Log error message
        logMessage('Failed to connect to socket');
        return;

    }

}

connection.send('\x02\x00\x01\x04\x26\x2D');
```

[image]

I have tried sending this as a string and json object as `msg.payload` but it is not triggering the device as I expect it to such as when I run the normal JS function in a browser.

What would be an appropriate format to send this hex string in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to send is a buffer and the inject node can't generate a buffer at this point. The easiest way to do this will be to insert a function node between the inject and the WebSocket Out node.

The function node should contain something like:

```
msg.payload = Buffer.from("\x02\x00\x01\x04\x26\x2D");
return msg;
```

This will swap the payload for a buffer with the right values.

EDIT:
For NodeJS 0.10.x you should use something like as Buffer.from() was introduced in NodeJS 4.x:

```
msg.payload = new Buffer("\x02\x00\x01\x04\x26\x2D");
return msg;
```

Comment: I gave this a shot but received an error in the debugger. It's quite long but along the lines of `TypeError: Object function Buffer(subject, encoding, offset) { if (!(this instanceof Buffer)) { return new Buffer(subject, encoding, offset); } var type; // Are we slicing? i`. Full error here: http://pastebin.com/bEBfhCZp

Comment: What version of NodeJS are you using to run Node-RED?

Comment: Node-RED version: v0.15.3
Node.js  version: v0.10.29

Comment: I also tried doing something like this (Different command for a test): `msg.payload = new Buffer([0x02, 0x00, 0x02, 0x04, 0x20, 0x28]); `

Comment: I've edited the answer for pre Node 4.x. You should probably look at upgrading via the script here: http://nodered.org/docs/hardware/raspberrypi

Comment: Thanks, will give the upgrade a try and try your original answer.

Comment: Bummer, upgraded to the newest version and gave your suggestion a try with no result :/ - The debug output looks different now in the format of `[ 2, 0, 2, 4, 32, 40 ]` but other than that, not getting any response from the connected web socket.

Comment: Ahh this worked - The socket was sending the entire message, not just the payload. Thanks so much!